# Android 5.0+ multi-user feature: how detailed can you set user restrictions?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tablet, multi-user

I'm thinking about buying my first **tablet** in the near future. The main goal is to use it for very different parts of my daily life (private, university, two different music groups, some private business, etc....).

I'd like to keep all those parts separated, that is why I want to create various users and use android's multi-user feature. Until today I only have a htc smartphone, with android 4.2 and also only one user of course -> no experience with multi-user @ android at all...

I already bought a lot of apps and I'd like to (re-)use those apps (or at least some of them) on all of my different users in the future. This means I will be using one google/play account only, for every user the same account. BUT I'd like to restrict some users from accessing this google-account's calendar-data for example.

Is this possible? Is it possible to make the restriction-settings in such a detailed way (allowing access to play but restricting access to calendar, email, etc. for example?)

If so, this would be really great. Since i never had the opportunity to hold one of the new android tablets in my hands I just don't know. I hope someone of you can help me :)

Thanks in advance!

All the best
ben

Answer (score 0):

When any app is installed on your android device, the app is visible to all the users. However, the data of each is user will be different (private to each user).